# Who is right in defining the meaning of a word: meta or challenge?

Tags: discussion, quine

This is a crazy (crazy as in crazy weird) issue. If a challenge defines a quine as

> A quine is a non-empty computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output.

And the meta says:

> A quine is payload-capable if it can be extended, in some systematic manner, to include a "payload" of additional code capable of performing arbitrary computation, in addition to printing its source code. A payload-capable quine, in its base form, must include all the code necessary to carry and execute a payload, even if no actual payload is present.

And

> A quine is a non-empty computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output.

Also

> It must be possible to identify a section of the program which encodes a different part of the program. ("Different" meaning that the two parts appear in different positions.)
> Furthermore, a quine must not access its own source, directly or indirectly.

They are all from different people. The first is a user the second Kevin Workman and the third is Martin. Who is right? And if a challenge defines a quine as different wouldn't that override the meta?

The issue arose from my answer to "Golf you a quine for great good" that follows. Would it be valid?

## HQ9+ 12 bytes (non cheating)

```
Hello World!
```

HQ9+ is a bit cheaty with the use of Q to quine. But if you write a program in it with `Hello World!` it detects the H and prints `Hello World!` and thus quines.

[Relevant chat transcript starts here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36038760#36038760)

Comment: If you have a question for clarification on this, you should post in chat or add a comment to the duplicate question you referenced.

Comment: @mbomb007 uhh in chat it was very split

Comment: @DownChristopher Well chat is only whoever is on at the time. Use the meta consensus, shown with votes.

Comment: Isn't it irrelevant? HQ9+ is not a programming language as defined in meta, so you can't use it for answers anyway.

Comment: The meta discussion defines "**proper** quine". Challenges can accept improper quines, too.

Answer (score 3):

## How to resolve rules:

1. All rules apply, including meta and rules posted on the question.
2. If there are two rules that conflict:  The posted question takes priority, followed by the most upvoted meta answer.

In your case:

The definition of a quine in the question "`A quine is a non-empty computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output`" does *not* conflict with the meta answers.

However, on the meta, we have two alternatives that *are* competing:

1. "`It must be possible to identify a section of the program which encodes a different part of the program`"
2. "`Solutions must be payload-capable, and must not read their source code or use string eval`"

The first one is the most upvoted one, and therefore takes priority.